Lamba Performance is very slow while fetching data from S3
I am beginner in AWS and want to get some advice for the below design that we are trying to implement at our side .
We are reading and fetch the content of bulk json files from S3 in the output response by AWS Lamda through API Gateway.
Inside the Lamda we are having a python code which is reading the files from S3 and combining  the content of the json files in an array and getting the same in the response.
After that the response is being received by external application through API gateway.
Below is the python code for the same :-
import boto3
import json
import zipfile

from datetime import datetime as dt


client = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = ‘testlocalS3’

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=‘Test/‘)
    isDeleted =event['isDeleted']
    column1 =event[‘column1’]
    publishDate =dt.fromisoformat(event['publishDate'])
    file_list = []

    for page in page_iterator:
        for Contents in page['Contents']:
         file_list.append(Contents['Key'])
    #print(file_list)
    result=[]
    for key in file_list:
     head_response = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
     FileLastModifiedDate=dt.fromisoformat(str(head_response['LastModified'].replace(tzinfo=None)))
     
     if (FileLastModifiedDate>=publishDate):
         data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
         content = data['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")  # Read and decode content once
        # Check if the file is empty
         if not content:
            print(f"Skipping empty file: {key}")
            continue
         
         json_response = json.loads(content)
         print(json_response)
         if (str(json_response['isDeleted'])==isDeleted and str(json_response['column1']) in column1):
             for item in json_response['column1']['column2’] :
                if (item[‘column3’]!=‘SomeData'):
                    result.append(json_response)

    return (result) 

Now the performance is very  slow and we are having a hard time  to get the response when there is a large list of file like 1000 json files in S3.
Can you please advice on the enhancement of the performance which seems a blocker for this design ?

The design is just bad if you expect a quick response, listing and then getting thousand of files will take a while. How many files do you have, what performance are you experiencing, what are you expecting instead / what would be the target performance?
I would drop the head before the get because that is just an extra network request and you get all the data in the get anyway (and nothing else before you start reading from the Body). And you will need some multi threading and parallelization in the lambda to not send the requests sequentially.

We added the head because if the files does not fall in the date range we dont want to enter and read the files.
If we drop the head then I would have to read the the contents even if the files don't fall in the range.

I know the reason for your implementation but I am saying that they are not fully correct. GetObject does not return the full object, it returns all the metadata plus a readable stream in Body containing the object - if you do not read the stream you have the same number of requests and roughly the same request size. but if you later read the Body then you have saved one extra request. If you really care you need to implement both approaches and properly measure and compare the runtime.

Why are you calling head_object thousands of time when you have the exact same data from the list_objects call?
